# Second Font Awesome icon displaying on hover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

In my navbar dropdown, when I hover over the links, the icons (icon-group, icon-plus) also have another icon (icon-filter) show up. This only happens on the bootstrap down down menu. I can't find any reference in the source file to the "icon-filter" class being applied.

You can view the incorrect icons in the dropdown at the link below.
http://agile-ocean-8233.herokuapp.com/

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
gem 'pg', :group => :production
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'font-awesome-rails'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.11.4", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.2.1", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.0", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.9.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.1.2", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.1.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.1.0.1"
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.2"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.8"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.4"
gem "stripe", ">= 1.7.4"
gem "stripe_event", ">= 0.4.0"
gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.1", :group => :development
gem "letter_opener", :group => :development
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'thin'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Application.css.scss

```
 *= require_self
 *= require 'font-awesome'
 *= require_tree .
*/
.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 -20px; /* negative indent the amount of the padding to maintain the grid system */
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Navigation dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown" id="client_menu">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href='#'>
    Clients <b class="caret"></b> 
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to 'Clients <i class="icon-group"></i>'.html_safe, clients_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'New Client <i class="icon-plus"></i>'.html_safe, new_client_path %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'font-awesome';
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

Comment: any chance you can put this in jsfiddle or do you have this on a site somewhere? something i noticed is that you dont need require font-awesome in your application.css.scss file, might not fix the problem though

Comment: I've added a link to the heroku app. It is below as well.  
http://agile-ocean-8233.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Also, I removed the require font-awesome in the application.css.scss file, and it broke the app. Is this because I loaded font-awesome through a gem instead of manually?

Comment: why isnt font-awesome being loaded through your bootstrap and override file? font-awesome comes with bootstrap, no need for a gem

Comment: for now put require font awesome back in your application file and solve the hover status first, then we will look at font-awesome rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your problem is this

```
 background-image: url(/assets/glyphicons-halflings-white-27ae535ced0dc82c64894d9 etc
```

When you hover over the dropdowns/anchor tags (so client and new client) the above is being invoked, when you remove it using chrome's developer tools for example the problem disappears.

Have you tried viewing your site on firefox? it is not rendering the css assets. take a look. is this project on github? I could prob find it then in the source code

and now its not rendering in chrome? same error

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I'm not sure how to change it however. The github project is here:  

https://github.com/smcavinney/PetSit  

The css assets issue was from removing the require font-awesome from the application.css.scss.

Comment: is this project on github?

Comment: How did you install twitter bootstrap? did you follow this https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails. because i dont think you did

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem.

Comment: my suggestion would be to stick with css/less as it seems you are having problems with using the sass gem, plus is there anything you want to do with sass that you cant achieve with CSS/LESS/JQuery etc. I use CSS/LESS and have had no complaints so far

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll try that out and see if it works out.

Comment: I made the change to the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, and changed over to less. Everything works as expected, thanks!